# Load / NTLM Auth / cache issue in Firefox and Sharepoint on premises

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, cache, ntlm, firefox

I am experiencing a very weird issue when trying to access sharepoint on premises from new Firefox version (Quantum >v60.0), (browser runnig on a windows computer).

**SCENARIO:**

- Firefox is correctly configured for using NTLM for Auth ( FF about:config).
- Sharepoint 2013 on premises. Firefox ESR 60.
- Sharepoint is loaded just fine in IE & Chrome, however, Firefox fails to fully load the site, apparently, on a random basis. After a page refresh, FF manages to load the site just fine for some time ( I guess this time is based on the ntlm auth cookie expiration ).
- Other firefox users experience the same issue.
- Previous ESR Firefox version, v52.0, doesn't present this issue or have any problem in loading SP sites.
- no errors are shown in Firefox console, in terms of javascript, XHR, etc

**SUMMARY:**

The problem is that FF (>v60.0) has issues to succesfully load the page, or sometimes even to start to load the page. However, **if Firefox cache is disabled,** **this issue doesnt happen at all.**

**"Network"** tab from the FF developer tools, lets you notice that load process stops at some point ( You can see in the source code that some files/code has been downloaed, but not all of it), and it is only completed if you refresh the page, or disable cache.

*I can't find out which his the problem. Any ideas? thanks very much.*

Comment: What error messages do you get when it fails to authenticate? Also what protocol are you running SharePoint on? https or http?

Comment: http. There are no erros, it is just that sometimes all the sp files are loaded, and other times only a part of them are loaded. But there are no error in the console log or HTTP request. However, If you permantly disable the cache in firefox ( using the code inspector or about:config ), the load issue goes away

Comment: Do you get any distributed cache timeouts in ULS logs? Have you increased the default timeouts for DistCache?

Comment: Based on the symptoms, you might consider reporting this on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/. This is very unlikely to be a SharePoint issue.

Comment: Thanks I will create a ticket in bugzilla and check the distributed cache settings.

Comment: I have created the following ticket in bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1484149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I decided to report this issue to the mozilla development team. It turned out that the source of the issue was related to some cache racing problem. 
Current ESR version has already solved the issue.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1484149